# React Router 6 alpha 4 nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Giving the following sandbox, not sure to understand how to render the Bb component

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="a" element={<Aa />}>
          <Route path="b" element={<Bb />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Aa() {
  return (
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
  );
}

function Bb() {
  return <p>World</p>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-shadow-337zc?file=/src/App.js

browsing to /a/b only renders Aa component

Comment: Comprehensive tutorial for nested Routes in RR6: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

react-router v6 exposes an `Outlet` element that you must use inside your parent Route so that any nested children can be rendered by react-router-dom isnide of it

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="a" element={<Aa />}>
          <Route path="b" element={<Bb />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Aa() {
  return <p>Hello <Outlet /></p>;
}

function Bb() {
  return <p>World</p>;
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-hermann-lxof3)**

If you want only `Bb` to render at `a/b` you define it as a separate route like

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="a" element={<Aa />}/>
    <Route path="a/b" element={<Bb />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can read more about Route structuring in [depth here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts)

Comment: Okey thank you ! And how should I do if I only want Bb to be rendered on /a/b url ? I need Aa to only render a new routes component ? My case is I don't want to render Aa on /a/b but only on /a and Bb only on /a/b

Comment: Thank you that's perfect

Comment: Glad to have helped mate

Answer (score 1):

additional note to @Shubham Khatri's answer:

```
<Route path="a" element={<Aa />}>
    <Route path="b" element={<Bb />} />
</Route>
```

`/a/b/` will render

```
<Aa>
  <Bb />
</Aa>
```

If you want to display only `Bb` component, nested route is not the right way.

Read more [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts)